# I want to use bootstrap's cdn in my react project. Where and how do I insert the cdn?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am currently working on a React single page application and I cannot figure out where and how to place the `Bootstrap` `CDN` in my project for my bootstrap to work.

Also if somebody could suggest how to `npm` install bootstrap for your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use create-react-app there is a file in public/index.html or let's say in your index html page which you first  render use cdn there 
like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">  
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 3):

**CDN**

```
<HTML>
        <head>
    <!-- YOU CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body></body>
        </HTML>
```

**npm**

```
npm install bootstrap@3
```

require('bootstrap') will load all of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins onto the jQuery object. The bootstrap module itself does not export anything. You can manually load Bootstrap's jQuery plugins individually by loading the /js/*.js files under the package's top-level directory.

Bootstrap's package.json contains some additional metadata under the following keys:

less - path to Bootstrap's main Less source file
style - path to Bootstrap's non-minified CSS that's been precompiled using the default settings (no customization)

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

after this import this in App.js

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`